# Faceit counterstrike: How isn't this prisoner's dilemma?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, cheats, counter-strike, counter-strike-2

Here's what I understand:

- Regular csgo/cs2 matchmaking aka 'mm' has no intrusive anti-cheat.
- Faceit has intrusive anti-cheat but is very toxic. Usually, you're here only if you're at least Gold Nova 1, i.e. not silver.

Sounds like a prisoner's dilemma: If only one silver plays faceit, then that silver will have a bad time. However, if everyone, silver or not, plays faceit, then everyone benefits. Valve may even have incentive to include an anti-cheat.

**Question: In theory, how isn't this prisoner's dilemma in that if everyone hypothetically switched to faceit because of the ff?**

1. Things would things really be the same (for silvers...but maybe even for everyone else) in terms of toxicity and eventually everything else really. (I.e. Both prisoners confess.)
2. It doesn't necessarily work if anything more than a small minority played mm instead of faceit. (I.e. Only some prisoners confess. But in this case, the 2 person prisoner's dilemma requires 100% participation while this variation technically allows for a few dissenters.)
3. Things would necessarily be better because there's intrusive anti-cheat but is the same game.

**Idea**: The only thing I can think of is the '**you kinda need to know all maps**' difference, but I think this'd be similarly addressed if all players cooperate, but well idk maybe there's more than a small minority of people who really play only 1 map - enough to impact this strategy. (Btw, I think this might even be better for casual play in balancing the map choices: If you might have to play every map in competitive, then you'd wanna be familiar with all of them in casual, instead of just sticking to only the 'popular maps'... in fact there should be much less a concept of 'popular map'.)

**Note**: I played faceit only once. I haven't played competitive since 3 years ago in early 2021, except for 1 game towards the end of csgo. That game was the only shorter match - MR12 I think - I've ever played. I haven't played any competitive game in cs2.

Comment: The [[tag:counter-strike]] tag is for the original Counter-Strike (CS 1.6). There's no need to use it for questions about CSGO or CS2.